# How to compute signed difference between two 24 bit images?

Tags: opencv

I think if I use `cvSub(img1,img2,dimg,NULL)` then `dimg` only stores the absolute values after the difference. I declared `img1,img2,dimg` as `IplImage` and both `img1` and `img2` are 24 bit image (8 bits/channel).

How can I compute the signed difference of two images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your images(Mat files) to `CV_8SC1` for 1 channel images and `CV_8SC3` for three channel images by [convertTo](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto) and then use [subtract](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#subtract) to get your answer!

**Note**: Please use C++ version!

Comment: Thanks. Will it be like this? img1.convertTo(CvMat *img1Mat, CV_8SC3) and for subtraction can I still use cvSub?

Comment: `subtract` is the C++ version of `cvSub` according to the link provided